# Making minimal custom Debian ISO to recognize USB device

Tags: debian, usb

I'm using [Cubic](https://launchpad.net/cubic) to create a minimal ISO of Debian, based on one of the official ISOs.

The process goes like this:

1. Select the ISO image.
2. A chroot environment opens and let you manipulate the image.
3. Generate the modified ISO.

My goal is to have a bootable ISO (like Clonezilla) that runs my program to scan plugged USBs.

To reduce debian:

1. I start using [this official guide](https://wiki.debian.org/ReduceDebian)
2. Run Clonezilla (wich is based on Debian) in a virtual machine, and extract the packages installed into a file.
3. In my Cubic chroot I use the later file and remove all the packages except the ones on the file.
4. Install the packages (some may be not installed in Debian) from the file.

This process, so far, reduces the ISO to 350MB, give or take. Great.

Now I try the newly generated ISO in a virtual machine (VirtualBox), it boots Ok, I get to the root tty perfectly.

I insert a USB to the virtual machine, and then **I find that the system does not scan for USBs**. `lsblk`, `fdisk`, `blkid` don't see any USB.

- If I plug in the USB before the system starts, it does recognize it.

My questions, *maybe too vague*: **¿Is recognizing USB package dependent?¿Which ones?**

If not: **¿What part of the system performs this task?**

For every little change in the process, I must regenerate the ISO to test the changes, which takes a lot of time.